# Setting Button Image from Plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I am trying to load data from my .plist to my buttons I am creating programmatically. My plist files contain images. I want the images to then be added to my buttons I create when I call the .plist. Currently, I can only get the images names to display on the screen. Here is what I have tried.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Academic" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *buttonsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSLog(@"%@",buttonsArray);

    int positionX = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < [buttonsArray count] ; i++) {

        MainMenu *abingtonAcademic = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];

        UIButton *abAcademicButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [abAcademicButton setImage:abingtonAcademic forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        abAcademicButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, positionX, 300, 40);
        [self.mainMenuScroll addSubview:abAcademicButton];

        positionX += 50;

    }

    [self.mainMenuScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, positionX + 20)];

}
```

Comment: When you have the image name you should use `+ (NSImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name` to  create the image and then set this as image of the button. (provided that you have an image with this name in your Assets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect, you have not images in plist, but its names. So, you'll need images be in application's bundle. Than, you can set you button image with

```
[abAcademicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: abingtonAcademic] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But, if you have you images coded to NSData and stored to plist, than you should use

```
[abAcademicButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: abingtonAcademic] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```